# Запуск готового проекта laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Возникла проблема при запуске готового проекта Laravel.
Установил composer и curl. Из папки проекта пытаюсь запустить:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
PHP fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/myproject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path = '.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

В 17 строке написано следующее:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Т.е. не может найти файл autoload.php, папки vendor не существует в проекте.

Что я делаю не так? 
Также мне сообщили, что сам laravel ставить не надо.

Comment: В дистрибутиве Laravel папка vendor в .gitignore прописана. Если локально разрабатывал, а потом в свое репо выгрузил, то vendor туда не попадет. Приходиться на хостинг ее архивом заливать по ftp и распаковывать. У вас, случаем, не такая ситуация?

Comment: @pavelchervov не такая. Надо было просто выполнить php composer.phar install

Answer (score 4):

Решено: 
из корневой папки проекта нужно выполнить в терминале:

```
php composer.phar install
php composer.phar update
php artisan serve
```